# Take rows of ith duplicated index and put in i number of dataframes

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

This is a bit tricky to put into words, but I'll give it a try. I have a dataframe with duplicated indices as provided below.

```
a = [0.00000, 0.071928, 1.294, 2.592563, 0.000318, 2.575291, 0.439986, 2.232147, 6.091523, 2.075441, 0.96152]
b = [0.00000, 0.399791, 1.302446, 1.388957, 1.276451, 1.527568, 1.614107, 2.686325, 4.167600, 6.135689, 5.945807]

df = pd.DataFrame({'a' : a, 'b' : b})
df.index = [1,1,1,1,1,2,2,3,3,3,4]
```

I want the row of the first duplicated index for every number to be appended to df1, and the row of the second duplicated index to be appended to df2, etc; the first time indices 1, 2, 3, 4... n have a duplicate, those rows get appended to dataframe 1. The second time indices 1, 2, 3, 4...n have a duplicate, those rows get appended to dataframe 2, and so on. Ideally, it would look something like this if concatenated for the first three duplicates under the 'index' column:

[image]

Any idea how to go about this? I've tried to run df[df.duplicated(subset = ['index'])] in a for loop to widdle down the df to the very first duplicates, but it doesn't seem to work the way I think it will.

Comment: It's really hard to work from images, please edit your answer to include your table by `df.head(20).to_dict(orient='list')`. This will yield a dictionary that is easy to turn into a table. I believe the solution is going to be a combination of `cumcount` and `pivot`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Slicing out the duplicate indices via [`cumcount`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.cumcount.html) and using [`concat`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.concat.html) to stitch together the resulting sub-dataframes will do the job.

```py
cols = df.columns
df['id'] = df.index

pd.concat([df[df.groupby('id').cumcount()==i][cols] for i in range(0, max(df.groupby('id').cumcount().values))], axis=1)
```

Comment: Have you gone through the work of making a df from OP's image? If so can you please edit OPs question to include that table?

Comment: Not quite, I merely eye-balled a frame like it. Regardless, I fixed it up and will add it. :)